# Why is array undefined after pushing to it in vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm new to vuex and I have a problem which should work but it doesn't.

I have a list of products and I want to get a single item from that.

My state looks like this:

```
const state = {
  products: [
    {
      id: 1,
      manId: 3,
      name: "Samsung S7 Edge",
      price: 659,
      image:
        "https://www.boostmobile.com/content/dam/boostmobile/en/products/phones/samsung/s7-edge/black/device-front.png.transform/pdpCarousel/image.jpg",
      description:
        '5.5" Quad HD Super AMOLED | 12 MP Phase Detection Autofocus Rear Camera / 5 MP Front Facing Camera | Android Marshmallow 6.0 | Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac, Dual-Band, Wi-Fi Direct, Hotspot | Water-Resistant Features an IP68 Rating (30 Min. In 1m Of Water) | Low-Light Camera | Expandable Storage Up To 200 GB | Samsung Pay',
      manufacturer: {
        id: 3,
        name: "Samsung"
      }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      manId: 1,
      name: "iPhone 7",
      price: 769,
      image:
        "https://www.t-mobile.com/content/dam/t-mobile/en-p/cell-phones/apple/apple-iphone-7/matte-black/Apple-iPhone7-MatBlack-1-3x.jpg",
      description:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore enim eveniet fuga placeat velit. Dolorem minima nemo nulla perspiciatis totam. Consequuntur debitis dolorem eveniet illo magni nobis perspiciatis quidem quisquam.",
      manufacturer: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Apple"
      }
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Xperia XZ",
      price: 649,
      image:
        "https://notebookspecialista.hu/files/pix-product/xperia-xz-premium-silver-front.png",
      description:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore enim eveniet fuga placeat velit. Dolorem minima nemo nulla perspiciatis totam. Consequuntur debitis dolorem eveniet illo magni nobis perspiciatis quidem quisquam.",
      manufacturer: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Sony"
      }
    }... //<--rest of dummy data is here

  ],
  //product is used for storing a single item 
  product : [

  ]
};
```

I use an action when I go to a specific route

```
[TYPES.actions.productById]({ commit }, {id}) {
    console.log("id: ",id); //prints id correctly so that's not the problem
    commit(TYPES.mutations.productById,id);
  }
```

My mutation

```
[TYPES.mutations.productById](state,id){

    state.product = [];
    console.log("product before: ", state.product); //product before:  Array []
    state.product.push( state.products.find(x => x.id === id));

    console.log("product after:", state.product); //product after: Array [ undefined ]
  }
```

So for some reason I can't push an item from products to product. 
What's more weird that it works flawlessly on jsfiddle.

Even if I set a dummy item inside product and don't use actions/mutations just a getter, it will be undefined in my computed property in the component!

I have a lot of eslint warnings but those can't cause this I guess so I'm just lost...any ideas?

Comment: Actually I do that to reset my array to empty, The problem was that the id I get from the route is a string so I had to parse it to int.  Now I can get the product in the property, but when I try to access "product.name" "product.price" etc it's undefined.

Comment: If `product` is used for storing a single item as your comment says, is there a reason you are using an array?  And from your comment as far as you can't access the properties, could it be because you aren't accessing the product by the index? e.g. `product[0].price`

Comment: Yep, I changed product to not be an array, that solved my problem, thanks!  I can't believe it was that simple